# How to do a Cmd+Shift+F search of grayed out files in directory in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, command

When I do a `Cmd`+`Shift`+`F` search in VSCode, I get a list of all files containing the text I input... except for the .files & files in grayed-out directories (like the node_modules directory).

I'm assuming there's a command to bypass this that I'm not aware of, but I haven't been able to find it.

How do I go about this?